# Python Tkinter GUI - Using after() to run a function in the background of a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, sqlite

I'm making a GUI with Tkinter to support a Parkinson's tremor monitoring system for an embedded systems course. This is my first time using Python, and my first time doing object-oriented programming, so please excuse my likely terrible code & practices. My current program is a mix of some StackOverflow Q/A and my own functions. I've seen people ask somewhat similar questions and the answer has generally been to either multithread or use after(), but I'm trying to avoid multithreading if at all possible and my current issue is that my use of after() isn't achieving what I expect it to.

Basically, the goal is that the user can input a medication (name, dosage & frequency), which is then stored in an SQLite database. When it's time to take one of the medications stored in the database (timing determined by the 'frequency' parameter entered, it should trigger a switch to a page instructing the user to take that medication (MedAlert frame). While the program is timing/checking if it's time to switch, the rest of the GUI should operate normally.

My alarm function is here:

```
## Function to alert the user to take medication
    def alarm(self):
        ## Import data
        medData = self.retrieve_data()

        ## Seperate rows
        i = 0
        for row in medData:
            name, dose, freq, startTime, waitTime = str(row).split(",")

            array_startTime.append((startTime.replace("'","")).strip())
            array_waitTime.append((waitTime.replace("'","")).replace(")",""))

        ## For each medication, check if it's time to take it
            if (datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime.strptime(array_startTime[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(minutes = float(array_waitTime[i]))):
                self.switch_frame(MedAlert)

   i += 1
```

The .replace(), .strip() etc are just to remove the unncessary punctuation marks from the retrieved SQLite data. The goal is to have this function constantly running in the background, so that as soon as it detects that it's time to take a medication stored in the database, it switches the frame in the GUI. I'm currently using the after() function, like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = PDAS_GUI()
    gui.after(0, gui.alarm())
    gui.mainloop()
```

I can run everything, enter/delete medications, use the GUI, but the MedAlert screen is never triggered (tested using entered frequency of 0.01hrs [36 secs]. I get no errors at all in the output. Is the issue with my alarm() function itself, or the way that I'm trying to run it? Any help/guidance that you guys could provide would be very much appreciated! The full code is below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

import sqlite3

import time
import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('PDAS_db.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS medication (name VARCHAR, dose VARCHAR, freq VARCHAR, startTime VARCHAR, waitTime VARCHAR)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

array_startTime = []
array_waitTime = []

class PDAS_GUI(tk.Tk):

## Function for initialisation
    def __init__(self):               
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Home)

## Global temp variables for data entry
        self.shared_vars = {            
            "MedName": tk.StringVar(),
            "MedDose": tk.StringVar(),
            "MedFreq": tk.StringVar(),
            }

## Function to switch between frames
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):    
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self.frame is not None:
            self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = new_frame
        self.frame.pack()

## Function to store data to SQLite database
    def store_data(self, name, dose, freq):     
        startTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        waitTime = (float(freq) * 60)

        conn = sqlite3.connect('PDAS_db.sqlite')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute('INSERT INTO medication (name, dose, freq, startTime, waitTime) VALUES (?, ? ,?, ?, ?)', 
                    (str(name), str(dose), str(freq), str(startTime), str(waitTime)))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

## Function to retrieve data from SQLite database
    def retrieve_data(self):                
        conn = sqlite3.connect('PDAS_db.sqlite')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM medication')
        medData = cur.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return medData

## Function to alert the user to take medication
    def alarm(self):
        ## Import data
        medData = self.retrieve_data()

        ## Seperate rows
        i = 0
        for row in medData:
            name, dose, freq, startTime, waitTime = str(row).split(",")

            array_startTime.append((startTime.replace("'","")).strip())
            array_waitTime.append((waitTime.replace("'","")).replace(")",""))

        ## For each medication, check if it's time to take it
            if (datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime.strptime(array_startTime[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(minutes = float(array_waitTime[i]))):
                self.switch_frame(MedAlert)

            i += 1

## Home Page
class Home(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        tk.Label(self, text = 'PARKINSONS DISEASE ASSISTANCE SYSTEM').pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x' , pady = 10)
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Medication', 
                  command = lambda: master.switch_frame(Medication2)).pack()

## Page to enter new medications
class Medication2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        tk.Label(self, bd = 50, text="Add New Medication").grid(row = 0, column =1)

        tk.Label(self, bd = 100, text="Medication Name:").grid(row=1, column = 0)
        MedName = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.master.shared_vars["MedName"])
        MedName.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        tk.Label(self, bd = 100, text="Dosage:").grid(row=2, column = 0)
        MedDose = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.master.shared_vars["MedDose"])
        MedDose.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        tk.Label(self, bd = 100, text="Frequency (hours):").grid(row=3, column = 0)
        MedFreq = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.master.shared_vars["MedFreq"])
        MedFreq.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        tk.Button(self, text = "Finish", 
                   command = lambda: master.switch_frame(Medication4)).grid(row = 4, column = 1)

## Page that confirms & stores new medications
class Medication4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        tk.Label(self, text="Verify New Medication").grid(row = 0 , column = 1)

        MedName = self.master.shared_vars["MedName"].get()
        MedDose = self.master.shared_vars["MedDose"].get()
        MedFreq = self.master.shared_vars["MedFreq"].get()

        tk.Label(self, text = "Please confirm your new medication:\nMedication Name: %s\n Dosage: %s\n Frequency: %s\n" % (MedName, MedDose, MedFreq)).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        tk.Button(self, text = "Confirm & Return Home",
                 command=lambda: [master.switch_frame(Home), master.store_data(MedName, MedDose, MedFreq)]).grid(column = 1)

## Alarm page
class MedAlert(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text = "Medication Alert!\n\n Take %s of %s." % (str(dose),str(name))).grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
        tk.Button(self, text = "Medication Taken",
                          command = lambda: master.switch_frame(Home)).grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

## Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = PDAS_GUI()
    gui.after(0, gui.alarm())
    gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code for us to sift through. Please try to remove all of the code that is not relevant to the question being asked, and create a proper [mcve].

Comment: Reverse this two lines: `gui.mainloop()
    gui.after(0, gui.alarm())`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Bryan Oakley. I've tried to remove every unncessary line, including formatting/graphics things. Shortened it by ~150 lines. Hopefully it's easier to see what's going on now. I've tried stovfl solution of swapping the mainloop and alarm, as well as just passing a call to alarm: `gui.after(0, gui.alarm)`, but still having the same error, alarm is never triggering.

Comment: I don't know if it's the whole problem, but this definitely part of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47852365/7432