# Time interval in tkinter before switching frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need help for my code. I want to change the background of my button before switching the page or frame. In my code, the frame switches but I don't see the button changing it's background color and if I remove the code to switch the frame which is this `frame1.after(2000, show_frame(frame2))` which has a delay and it works.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

root.rowconfigure (0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure (0, weight = 1)

frame1 = Frame (root, bg = "yellow")
frame2 = Frame (root, bg = "blue")


def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

for frame in (frame1,frame2):
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

#the problem is here
def to_frame2():
    b.config(bg = "black")
    frame1.after(2000, show_frame(frame2))

b = Button(frame1, text = "Frame 2", command = to_frame2)
b.pack()

show_frame(frame1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `frame1.after(2000, show_frame(frame2))` needs to be `frame1.after(2000, show_frame, frame2)`

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for answering and your suggestion works! Can you explain it to me? :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47852221/7432