# Python ttkbootstrap.tableview : auto-refresh tableview generated from a database

Tags: python, tableview, ttkbootstrap

Is there a way to auto-refresh tableview from a database ? maybe with a button or auto ?
I Created a Manual Refresh Visual Button to do the job "click_Refresh()"
can any one help ?

CODE :

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import cx_Oracle
from ttkbootstrap.tableview import Tableview
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
from ttkbootstrap.toast import ToastNotification

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('****', '****', service_name='****')
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'****', password='****', dsn=dsn_tns)
cur = con.cursor()
rowdata = cur.execute('''SELECT USER_ID,EMAIL,USER_STATUS from table
    ''')

def click_Refresh():
    # Display message
    toast.show_toast()

coldata = [
    {"text": "USER_ID", "stretch": True},
    {"text": "EMAIL", "stretch": True},
    {"text": "USER_STATUS", "stretch": True},
]

app = ttk.Window(themename="superhero", size=(100, 100))
app.geometry("1000x500")
app.title("USER MANAGEMENT")
app.resizable(True, True)
app.place_window_center()

label = ttk.Label(app, text="USER MANAGEMENT VERSION 1.0", bootstyle=DEFAULT)
label.pack(pady=5)
label.config(font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))

button_frame = ttk.Frame(app)
button_frame.pack(pady=10, padx=2, fill="x")
ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Refresh", bootstyle="OUTLINE-SUCCESS",
           command=click_Refresh).pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=5)

dt = Tableview(
    master=app,  # The parent widget
    paginated=False,
    searchable=True,
    height=50,
    autoalign=False,
    autofit=True,
    pagesize=30,
    coldata=coldata,
    rowdata=rowdata,
    bootstyle=DANGER,
)

dt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=10, pady=10)
dt.autofit_columns()  # Fit in current view


# Define the toast notice (temporary message)
toast = ToastNotification(
    title="Refresh Notifcation",
    message=("Database version:", cx_Oracle.version,
             "Database version:", con.version,
             "Client version:", cx_Oracle.clientversion()
             ),
    duration=9000,
    bootstyle=DARK,
    alert=True,
)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself to get past our quality filters. If you are prompted to add more detail, _add more detail_.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like: app.after(3000, CheckStatus())

found this idea here: [Tkinter after method executing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852221/tkinter-after-method-executing-immediately)

Comment: Many thanks for the IDEA. Will you help me with that? Do I have to create a function which repeats the cursor?  

def CheckStatus(self):
    rowdata = cur.execute('''SELECT USER_ID,EMAIL,USER_STATUS from table
    ''')

app.after(3000, CheckStatus())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am still researching this... however, I am coming to understand that your table code in a function might be the way to go... again, researching.